# Code Sense in Objective C if We Don't Know the First Letter

Tags: objective-c, xcode, intellisense, codesense

Okay the intellisense or code sense in objective c seems to fire only if we press some letter.

What about if I do not know the first letter of the an object method and I prefer to know ALL the methods a class support.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key.  It will show you a list of all possible autocompletions.